# How To Get Element To Hide When Webpage Is Loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get a select option to hide when the webpage is loaded and I have used

```
s2.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

To do so but It will only hide the second select button once the first one has been manipulated. I am trying to make it so that when the webpage first loads it isn't there until the category genre has appeared.

```
function populate(s1, s2)   {   
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";  
    s2.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    if(s1.value == "genre") {
        s2.style.visibility = "visible";    
        var optionArray = ["|", "rap|Rap", "r and b|R And B", "rock|Rock", "indie|Indie", "dance|Dance"];
    } else {

    }
    for(var option in optionArray) {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the visibility of that element in css before running any js code.

```
#s2 {
  visibility: 'hidden'
}
```

Comment: Exactly this.  Start with the element invisible, then make it visible when you need it.